# Animate a circle being drawn using Paper.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I'm trying to animate a circle being drawn using Paper.js.

As the circle tool is just a quick access for instantiating a path constructed via moveTo/arcTo etc, there are no arguments to support start and end angles (for open pie chart-like circles).

What I am looking for is a way to animate the circle being drawn from it's first point to an angle of my choice at a certain radius.

The actual canvas [specification allows for explicit startAngle and endAngle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) to be specified. If this was the case within Paper.js I could easily achieve what I am looking for. However,  within Paper.js I have yet to come across a method of replicating such control. I created something in Fabric.js that worked as Fabric's implementation of the circle shape used the same attributes as the arc command in the specification.

Does anyone know of a way this can be achieved so I can animate the endAngle?

Comment: Canvas's native drawing commands are available in a Path -- see [`Path.Arc`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#path-arc-from-through-to)

Comment: Yes I have seen that but there's quite a difference between the augments of the native arc and paper's implementation. 'Through' seems totally abstract as a value when trying to animate the drawing of a circle. At least in my head, I don't see how it can be animated to show the drawing of a circle. Can you even manipulate the 'from', 'through' and 'to' attributes once the path has been drawn? They don't appear to be accessible properties.

Comment: You can set up an animation loop: Remove the old smaller arc and add a new larger arc. ;-)

Comment: Thanks but isn't that quite inefficient? Also, when I am drawing a circle I can create the 'from' and 'to' points but have no idea how to create the 'through' point. Any ideas?

Comment: All canvas animation involves erasing the canvas and redrawing the updated shapes. You can use trigonometry to calculate from, through, to. Give it a try. If you can't manage. I'll post an answer after dinner. :-)

Comment: I take your point about the redrawing of canvas at runtime.... I'm new to this convention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a conversion function that accepts html5 canvas arc arguments and returns the `from, through, to` arguments needed for a Paper.js arc.

```
function canvasArcToPaperArc(cx,cy,radius,startAngle,endAngle,strokecolor){
    var startX=cx+radius*Math.cos(startAngle);
    var startY=cy+radius*Math.sin(startAngle);
    var endX=cx+radius*Math.cos(endAngle);
    var endY=cy+radius*Math.sin(endAngle);
    var thruX=cx+radius*Math.cos((endAngle-startAngle)/2);
    var thruY=cy+radius*Math.sin((endAngle-startAngle)/2);
    var from = new Point(startX,startY);
    var through = new Point(thruX,thruY);
    var to = new Point(endX,endY);
    return({from:from, through:through, to:to});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post the function. So in order to find the 'through' position you are just taking an average of the current 'from' and 'to'? I did think about that last night but I appreciate your input and I will give this a go today :)